# Excel Macro to Trim a cell value

Tags: excel, visual-studio-macros

I have to Trim a cell value thru macro. I have a cell where I am getting a value like "20170411 675432". Here you can see there a space in between 1 and 6. I want to remove that space so that I can get the field value as "20170411675432"
Thanks

Comment: you really want to do this only with macro? there are easier ways to do with formulas

Comment: Macro only. Anyway if you have any formula, pls post here so that I can get some idea.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Function trimacelll(cellalue As Variant)
    trimacelll = Replace(CStr(cellalue), " ", "")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as you have asked for a formula,

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")`

`A1` should contain the value

Comment: @SmrutiRMohanty unfortunately no. Please upvote if you found this useful...